# How can I remove everything except a particular string?

Tags: html, regex, notepad++

I have around a thousand html documents and I'm trying to remove everything except the string contained within `<div class="content">*</div>`

I tried finding `.*(<div class="content">\S*?</div>).*` and replacing with `$1` but that doesn't work

Comment: replace `.*` in your regex with `[\s\S]*?`

Comment: Why not use a tool for parsing HTML instead?

Comment: `div` elements are often nested. You may write a recursive regex, but it is a good idea to just use a simple XSLT based solution.

Comment: Wiktor, would you recommend any? This is totally new to me and I don't know what tools CAN be used. Thanks

Comment: Msxml, Saxon....